# MySQL select top N rows for each category

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get top 2 latest rows from each category, and this can be scaled later on so I might for example get top 4 rows instead of top 2.

here is how my table looks like

```
  Id   | category_id | created_at
------ | -----------   ----------
   1   |      1      | 2017-12-01
   2   |      2      | 2017-12-02
   3   |      4      | 2017-12-03
   4   |      2      | 2017-12-04
   5   |      1      | 2017-12-05
   6   |      1      | 2017-12-06
   7   |      3      | 2017-12-07
   8   |      4      | 2017-12-08
   9   |      4      | 2017-12-09
   10  |      3      | 2017-12-10
   11  |      5      | 2017-12-11
```

I want to get the latest 2 rows (based on the created_at column) ids so I want the output to be something like

```
      Ids     
    ------ 
       5   
       6   
       2   
       4   
       7
       10
       8
       9
       11
```

I'm doing something like

```
select * from table
inner join (
    select * from table
    order by category_id, created_at
    limit 2
) as tb
on tb.id = table.id and tb.category_id = table.category_id
```

Obviously it's not working, just wanted to share what I reached so far.
Is there a way to do that in MySQL?

**EDIT**

I actually did this and it kinda worked

```
SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT *, 
                  @count := IF(@current_category = category_id, @count + 1, 1) AS count,
                  @current_category := category_id 
       FROM table
       ORDER BY category_id, created_at DESC
     ) ranked
   WHERE count <= 2;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a pain in MySQL than it should be.  Probably the easiest way is to use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = category_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := category_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := -1) params
      order by category_id, created desc
     ) t
having rn <= 2;
```

Comment: I've edited my question above and it worked, the answer you have is kinda similar to mine as well. thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your answer is not guaranteed to work, because you set variables and then use them in different expressions.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select`.

Answer (score -2):

I would go with something like this:

```
select * from table group by category_id order by created_at limit 2
```

My mySql skills are a bit rusty but this (or the concept of it) should do the trick.

Comment: that will only get you the first 2 rows from the whole result

Comment: sorted by `created_at`, so it will return the top 2 items

Comment: yeah exactly, what I want is to get top 2 from **each** category I have sorted by created_at. so if I have multiple categories, your query will get me the top 2 from the whole result regardless of category sorted by created_at of course.

Comment: i remembered that this would limit the result of each "group", my mistake